# How to launch classic Outlook from the command line?

Tags: command-line, microsoft-outlook

I'm trying to create a shortcut that launches Outlook's calendar in its own window:
So far I have the shortcut setup:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select Outlook:Calendar
```

However, this seems to launch "new" Outlook instead of "classic" Outlook.

I get an error message saying new outlook doesn't support this feature.

I'm aware that you can make a registry setting to disable "new" Outlook but I don't wish to make this change globally.

Is there a way to provide a commandline parameter to tell it to use classic Outlook?

Comment: Is this an enterprise environment, or a personal device?

Comment: The basic shortcut you show is what I use here on two machines..  Can you open Outlook and switch back to Desktop?

Comment: @music2myear this my windows 10 laptop so personal device (not managed)

Comment: @john not sure what you are asking here?

Comment: I checked my Office Desktop shortcut and it is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE

Comment: You need to see if new Outlook allows you to switch back to traditional Outlook. Microsoft has a bad habit of removing needed features in "new" Apps.

Comment: @John yup, that works so it kind of is a workaround under the hood it sets the registry key so it doesn't quite allow me to continue to use new outlook for my mail app but launch classic for my calendar  but as you confirmed the shortcut does work with classic outlook thanks for the nudge.. i just reverted back